# How to Access android.hardware.SensorPrivacyManager in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to make an Android app that creates a Quick Settings Tile to toggle on & off all sensors. In essence, I am trying to recreate the 'Sensors Off' tile available in Developer Settings. (Because developer settings, & hence the tile, is only available to the main profile, not other user profiles--I am on GrapheneOS.)

According to the documentation for Sensors Off at https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/sensors-off , the tile is implemented using `android.hardware.SensorPrivacyManager`. However, in the Android SDK (30) in Android Studio, there is no `android.hardware.SensorPrivacyManager` available. There appears to be very little documentation of this. How can I access this manager in my app?